# I am facing jquery uncaught error while using google analytics code for pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento-2.0

I am using google analytical code for track pdf click event.
I am using this code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($) {
   jQuery(‘a[href$=".pdf"]’).click(function(){
  var pdf=jQuery(this).attr(‘href’);
   ga(‘send’,’event’, ‘pdf’, ‘download’, pdf);
   });

   });
  </script>
```

But I am facing Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token on line

```
jQuery(‘a[href$=".pdf"]’).click(function(){
```

Can anyone help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

The single quote(**‘**) you are using looks like the problem in the code. I tried the same code with this single quote(**'**), it's working fine. Try below-written code, it works fine.

```
jQuery('a[href$=".pdf"]').click(function(){
```

The error will keep coming up because, in all your code, these italic quotes are used. Maybe you need to change your keyboard settings.